# How to flip a textblock

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to flip a textBlock that already rotate to 90 degree?

Rotate is not same as flip. Hope you can help the following code.

```
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform();

 transform.Angle = 90.0;

txtBlock.RenderTransform = transform;   

from here, I want to flip
```

Comment: What do you mean by "flip"? Can you provide an example (e.g. screen mock-up) of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), something like:

```
var scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = -1 };
```

You can change ScaleX with ScaleY to switch axes, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional `ScaleTransform` and then animate this transform if you want a smooth flipping animation.

```
      <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard_Flip">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="front"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
          <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="back"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
          <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
```

And here's the reverse flip animation.

```
      <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard_Reverse">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="back"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
          <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="front"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
          <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something in xaml, then try this:

```
<TextBlock Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,137,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="This is sample text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Flip in y direction needs you to set the composite transform `ScaleY="-1"`